# Have localhost with dual boot (Windows/Ubuntu) share htdocs & mysql databases with XAMPP

Tags: dual-boot, mysql, xampp, localhost, apparmor

I just got a new machine with dual boot Ubuntu+Windows 8.1 and set up a localhost using XAMPP in a way that allows me to edit and preview the files on both OSes (so htdocs and mysql databases have to be shared).

So, in Windows, no problem: XAMPP installed, moved htdocs and mysql folders to new location quite easily (by changing some configuration files), all tested and it works, great!

For Ubuntu I used LAMP and successfully changed the datadir BUT the wordpress database created in Windows could not be read due to an InnoDB error so I decided to install XAMPP (LAMP was completely removed via console following instructions, nothing remains).

I changed the htdocs location for XAMPP on Ubuntu the same way I did in Windows, using the httpd.conf file and changing "DocumentRoot" and "Directory". This is tested so I know it works. MySQL also works if I use the default directory for its databases, this was also tested.

I tried adding the "datadir" location in the my.cnf file for MySQL BUT at that point the MySQL in XAMPP does not start (gives "Starting" for a few seconds then Stops - red light).
This problem can apparently be solved by changing `usr.sbin.mysqld` in apparmor (which I did when I tried to use LAMP) except that I cannot find `usr.sbin.mysqld` in `/etc/apparmor.d`

So, given that `usr.sbin.mysqld` exists *only* in the `cache` folder of `apparmor.d` and that said file can't be read by gedit (gives only red squares and gibberish in UTF-8), *how can I solve this problem?*

Comment: It is indeed too long to read..please ask a concise question.